# Black screen after grub menu since 3.16.0-36 kernel update

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, updates, screen

After updating Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (64 bit) from kernel version 3.16.0-34 to 3.16.0-36, when I boot the system I can see the grub menu correctly, but if I choose the 3.16.0-36 kernel a black screen appears not the login screen.

- Booting from the 3.16.0-36-recovery mode works and if I select to resume booting it goes on normally till login and Unity desktop loading, though graphics performance is much slower than usual.
- Booting from the 3.16.0-34 works without any problems.

I have waited for the 3.16.0-37 update to see if something changes but I got the same behavior as with 3.16.0-36.

Here there are details of my system:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64 bit

  (installed it directly from the 14.04.2 iso, so this is not an upgrade from 14.04.1) + Win7 Pro 64 bit in dual boot
- Laptop model: HP Zbook 14 G2, Intel i7 5500u processor, 16 GB of RAM
- Graphics: Intel HD 5500u Integrated +   AMD FirePro m4150 1GB GDDR5 discrete.

  (note that I have no proprietary driver installed and the system is currently working on the Intel graphics with open source drivers; I have also the radeon 7.4.0 open source drivers formally installed, but they do not seem to recognize the AMD card which is therefore actually disabled).

Comment: Thank you for the question editing, it is actually much clearer now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every Broadwell is affected.

I have the same problem (blank screen when booting my broadwell-based thinkpad) under trusty. My current work-around is to use the previous kernel 3.16.0-34, or, to boot with -36 in recovery mode and then choose 'resume normal boot' (which then goes through fine).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1449401

Answer (score 1):

Install the 3.16.0-37.51 kernel (notice the 51) that released yesterday with apt-get update and upgrade. It worked for my broadwell cpu.

Comment: It is all already explained in the bug link posted above. But thank you anyway (the upgrade worked for me also).